# Design Patterns - Designing classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am new to designing and structuring the classes and recently started to learn patterns based approach in designing the classes.

I would like to know which approach is better and the reasons for why it is better.

1. My first approach is to accept an object at default constructor level and run associated methods on it.  Construction of the object might take class from some other class instance or thru some static methods.
2. Second approach is to accept object thru a constructor and run methods on it.

So far, I have created my design something similar to below code patterns.

```
public class  TestPattern
{
    // Some X method or method of some other object is
    // taking care of constructing Object in it's client code

    MyObject object= MyObject.GetInstance(10); 

    public TestPattern()
    {
        System.err.println("Status of MyObject: "+object);
    }

    public TestPattern(MyObject object)
    {
        this.object=object;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        object.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new TestPattern().run();

        // Constructor is directly responsible
        //for creating object in it's client code.

        new TestPattern(new MyObject(25)).run(); 
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyObject
{
    private int n=0;
    public MyObject(int n)
    {
        this.n=n;
        System.out.println("Creating "+this);
    }                   

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Value: "+n;
    }

    public static MyObject GetInstance(int n)
    {
        return new MyObject(n);
    }

    public void execute()
    {
            System.out.println("Executing "+this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try to learn about classes by taking some real-world scenarios into consideration. Whatever you're trying to accomplish with this test class it's a little bit confuse. Try to describe in a short sentence what do you want from your object/class (e.g., The program should create 10 instances of a CAR object, each CAR instance will present a different registration number/license).

Comment: What is the difference between these? "1. My first approach is to accept an object at default constructor level and run associated methods on it."  "2. Second approach is to accept object thru a constructor and run methods on it."   Besides the phrase "at default constructor level" these sentences are the same. What do you mean by this phrase and how does it differentiate the two?

Comment: "Client class will never be responsible in constructing the instances directly". This is what I am trying to accomplish. In above example scenario,  TestPattern is my client class. 

1. Instance will be created directly by using MyObject's constructor in client class (i.e. TestPattern in this case) 

                 OR 

2) By using some third party class methods.

One approach is having direct exposure (directly assigning) and other is having indirect exposure (using other classes/methods)

So my question is which approach is better and why?

Comment: The language you are using is a bit confusing to me at least. But in my opinion injecting in the constructor or some `Set` method can be a good idea. This would help in writing test cases as then you would be programming to a supertype. Do lookup `Dependency Injection` Vs `ServiceLocator` as well.